# Laravel Virgin: Inject a Model In Controller as Dependency

Tags: php, laravel-5, dependency-injection, refactoring, legacy-code

In my inherited code in the Models there's some serious logic and I want to use the Laravel's Dependency Injection in order to load the models as Dependencies into the controller instead of Using the Laravel's provided Facades.

So here's a sample Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return View
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

But Instead of using the Facade `User` I want to be able to load it as dependency into the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
user App\Models\User

class UserController extends Controller
{

     /**
     * @var User
     */
     private $user=null;

     public function __construct(User $user)
     {
       $this->user=$user;
     }


    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return View
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => $this->user->findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

The reason why I want to do that is because I come from Symfony Background where the Dependency Injection Pattern Is heavily Erdosed. Also Dependency Injection is the Unit Test's best buddy, so I want to be able to unitilize the Dependency Injection that I am familiar with.

So I wanted to know whether I can inject the models where the logic exists in the Controllers Instead of using the Facade Pattern provided by laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register your route, you can use the model binding:

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('users/{user}', 'UserController@show');
```

Then in your controller, you can change your method to:

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    //
}
```

Where the `$user` will be the instance of `App\User` with the right id. For example, if the url is `/users/1`, the `$user` will contain the `App\User` with id `1`.

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding